# Not able to receive empty get request with express static in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, get

I am trying to fetch web pages using express static and below is the server code.

```
app.use(express.static('DIR/webfiles'));
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    console.log("got req");
    res.sendfile("login.html");
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log("got req");
    res.sendfile("login.html");
});
```

when I request for localhost:port/test (from browser), I am able to see login.html page and it prints "got req" on server end but when I request for localhost:port or localhost:port/ , I am getting some other file in webfiles folder. It does not print "got req". Is empty GET handler overridden by express static?

When I remove "app.use(express.static('DIR/webfiles'));" line, it is able to get empty GET request but doesn't work in way I want it to. Why it is not getting empty request and how to handle empty requests.

Comment: As far as i know `localhost:port` request automatically adds `/` to your request by default, which then becomes `localhost:port/`. So practically speaking you should get `login` page and not some other file.

Comment: localhost:port/ also gives same result

Comment: Try using the node core module `path = require ('path')` then use the `__dirname` and `path.join()` on your directory. That will ensure you hit your static target directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express will process the various route handlers (including the static middleware) in order of declaration.

If you request `/`, the static middleware will check for a file called `webfiles/index.html`, and if it exists, it will be returned.

To override this behaviour, make sure that you declare your own route handler *before* the static middleware declaration:

```
// This will match requests to `/` and since it's declared before
// the static middleware, it will get to handle those requests.
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log("got req");
  res.sendfile("login.html");
});

app.use(express.static('DIR/webfiles'));
```