# Express.js not saving session data

Tags: express, session-variables

I am building a web app and I would like to assign every client a random user ID (which should be retained across sessions). For this, I am setting the userId session variable.

```
const app = express()
app.use(session({
    secret: '1234',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
}))
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded())
app.use(express.static("public"))

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    req.session.userId = "user-" + utils.generateRandomString()
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
})

app.post("/api/auth", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.session)
    // auth logic
    res.send("Success")
})
```

So when the user navigates to `/`, the userId is set. This userId should be sent with the next request, to `/api/auth`, But the userId session variable is always undefined. This is what the `console.log` call prints:

```
Session {
  cookie: { path: '/', _expires: null, originalMaxAge: null, httpOnly: true }
}
```

**Edit:** here is the minimal client code that results in the problem:

```
fetch("/api/auth", {
    method: "POST",
    body: ""
}).then(res => res.text().then(text => console.log(text)))
```

I tried changing the order of the session middleware (placing it after cors, json, urlencoded and static) but to no avail.

So, how do I get around this?

Comment: This could be a client problem.  What is making the 2nd request?  Is it an Ajax call via Javascript?  If so, it has to have the right settings so that it will send the session cookie.   If it doesn't send the session cookie, then the next call will just make a new, empty session. 
 Please show the relevant client code making this request.

Comment: Yes, it is an AJAX call. But the session cookie (`connect.sid`) is included in the request, and I can see it in the browser's dev tools. The problem is probably in the server - it is not able to find the session with the given session ID.

Comment: Please show the relevant client code.  I see nothing wrong with the server code.

Comment: I've added the (minified) client code to the question.

Comment: You need the `credentials: 'include'` option with your `fetch()` so it will send the session cookie.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50698444/req-session-userid-returns-undefined-in-post-request/50698984#50698984.

Comment: I added this option, but still the session variables are not retained. The session cookie is getting sent both with and without `credentials: 'include'`. I can see it in the request headers: `Cookie: connect.sid=s%3AoU8cMQhqFyB2UWfA50aAn4VzceDeVLiv.v%2BzpKItM0eawyfZSp68198L4uB%2FNCXqvXYWzUGevQZw`

Comment: Add an `app.use()` handler that logs the exact incoming URL and headers on every request to see exactly what is arrive at your server.  I'm going to sleep now so can't help further.

Comment: Also, what happens if you just do two successive requests to `/` in the browser (not with Ajax) and log `req.session` in the `/` handler for each?

Comment: Regarding the custom `app.use()` handler, I can see the `connect.sid` cookie there. As for the two successive requests to "/", both print the same Session output included in the question. Also, good night and thanks for your help!

Comment: I found the problem: the `express.static("public")` middleware was overriding the `/` route, that even `console.log` calls inside this route's handler did not get executed. As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34357101/6649786), I placed the middleware after the `/` handler and it worked. I greatly appreciate the time you spent here, thank you!

Comment: So, your `/` route handler never executed and thus you never set `req.session.userId` in the first place?  Good find.  FYI, you can configure `express.static()` with the `index: false` option so it won't match `/` or you could remove `index.html` from the static directory so `express.static()` wouldn't find a file to use for `/`.   Using `index: false` is preferred since it makes the code more self documenting and not subject to slight ordering variations if this code gets modified in the future.

Comment: Exactly, the code that sets `req.session.userId` in the `/` handler was never executed. I will go with `index: false`, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close out this question with the answer, you can change this:

```
app.use(express.static("public"));
```

to this:

```
app.use(express.static("public"), {index: false});
```

The problem was that `express.static()` was "stealing" the `/` route (because it found an `index.html` file in its directory and thus the route handler that was supposed to run for that route and then execute this line of code was never being executed:

```
req.session.userId = "user-" + utils.generateRandomString()
```

So, it wasn't an issue of losing the cookie or the session.  It was an issue of the desired route handler was never executing so the `userId` value was never set in the session in the first place.